# Rango entre dos horas momentjs (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Estoy tratando de encontrar rangos entre dos horas dadas, en Si lo que deseo es hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo h1 = 20:00:00 y h2= 20:30:00

Lo que deseo es que el resultado final se igual a esto:

20:00:00--20:10:00--20:20:00--20:30:00 Es decir sumarle a la hora dada 10 minutos

Este es mi codigo:

```
.controller('General', function($scope){
   $scope.h1=moment("18:00:00",'HH,mm,ss').format('HH-mm-ss');
   $scope.h2=moment("21:00:00",'HH,mm,ss').format('HH-mm-ss');

  var rangoMinutos = function(h1, h2) {
      var rango= [];

      while (h1 <= h2) {
          rango.push(h1);
          h1.add(1,'hours');//NO SE SI ESTE BIEN ESTO
      }
      return rango;
  };

  var results1 = rangoMinutos($scope.h1, $scope.h2);
  alert(results1)//ver resultado de los rangos
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema que veo en tu código es que al generar el array estás añadiendo el mismo objeto moment n veces, con lo que al leerlo obtendrás n elementos iguales con la misma hora.

Si vas a crear un array de objetos moment deberías crear un nuevo objeto cada vez que añadas un elemento al array.

Échale un vistazo a este ejemplo:

```js
function calculateRange(start, end, minutes){
  var range = [];
  for(var hour = moment(start); hour.isBefore(end); hour.add(minutes, 'minutes') ){
    range.push(moment(hour));
  }
  range.push(moment(end));
  return range;
}


$(function(){
  $('#calculate').click(function(){
    var start = moment($('#startHour').val(), 'H:mm:ss');
    var end = moment($('#endHour').val(), 'H:mm:ss');
    var rangeArray = calculateRange(start, end, 10);
    var result = rangeArray.map(function(hour){ return hour.format('HH:mm:ss'); });
    $('#result').text(result.join(' --- '));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start: <input type="text" id="startHour" value="08:14:00"><br />
End: <input type="text" id="endHour" value="14:34:57"><br />
<button id="calculate">
Calculate
</button><br /><br />
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Esta muy interesante pero como lo haria con angularjs?

Comment: Pero la función de cálculo del rango es independiente de que uses angular o no.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver muchisimas GRACIAS :D

Comment: Una ultima duda como hago que tambien se agregue la ultima hora digamos en su ejemplo; que tambien se agregue al array el valor 14:34:57?

Comment: No tienes más que añadir "end" al array de resultados. He modificado el código para que la añada.

Comment: gracias Maestro me ha servido mucho :D

Answer (score 0):

No conozco MomentJS, pero lo primero que deberías hacer es convertir las dos horas a un formato que realmente puedas comparar sus diferentes.

```
const range = (start, end, interval) => {
    let s = start.split(':').map(s => s)
    let e = end.split(':').map(e => e)
    let time = []
    while (!(s[0] === e[0] && s[1] > e[1])) {
        time.push(s[0] + ':' + (s[1] < 10 ? '0' +s[1] : s[1]))
        s[1] += interval
        if (s[1] > 59) {
            s[0] += 1
            s[1] %= 60
        }
    }

    return time
}
console.log(range('18:80', '21:00', 30))
```